# Сохранится ли запятая в СПП, если части его разделены вставным предложением?

Tags: пунктуация, вставная-конструкция

Представьте себе - это не потребует особой фантазии - что вы решили пропустить по стаканчику с друзьями.

И можно ссылку на правило.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Представьте себе — это не потребует особой фантазии, — что вы решили пропустить по стаканчику с друзьями.**

[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=319):

> 3) перед вторым тире ставится запятая, если этого требует структура
>   второй части основного предложения или вставной конструкции:
>   *Прихвастнуть любил — **этот грех за ним водился,** — **может,** и тут что
>   приплёл для красного словца (Фурм.) — вторая часть начинается вводным
>   словом, которое требует выделения запятыми*;

В вашем случае за вставной конструкцией следует придаточная часть, которая требует запятой, значит, запятую ставим перед вторым тире.

Comment: Совсем недавно подобный вопрос уже задавался.